# Sending JSON in POST request with Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to integrate my Web services and I do not understand how to send a JSON object to the server using a POST request. I'm currently stuck, here is my code:

### Activity:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    PostInterface service = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("email", "device3@gmail.com");
        jsonObject.put("password", "1234");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String result = jsonObject.toString();

}
```

### PostInterface:-

```
public interface PostInterface {

    @POST("User/DoctorLogin")
    Call<String> getStringScalar(@Body String body);
}
```

### Request JSON:-

```
{
"email":"device3@gmail.com",
"password":"1234"
}
```

### Response JSON:-

```
{
  "error": false,
  "message": "User Login Successfully",
  "doctorid": 42,
  "active": true
}
```

Comment: what is data ?? you are sending ....??

Comment: i want to send "result" to server

Comment: i changed JSONObject to String and want to send server

Comment: what is problem you facing ??

Comment: Using POST request how can i send Parameter to server

Comment: yes using POJO class you can send the @Body

Comment: i clearly wrote above my code MainActivity i convert my JSON object to String that string result i want to send server that's what my requirement

Comment: if in beckhend it accept the String then use `@Field` instead of `@Body`.... OR convert your request into POJO and then send using `@Body`

Comment: oh either it any way please provide right solution with some details code i am very beginner

Comment: please provide the `request JSON` and `response JSON` after that i provide a useful answer .....................

Comment: ok wait i will provide

Comment: sushildlh  i provide Request and Response Json please provide solution

Comment: have look on the answer .............

Comment: works perfectly with `RequestBody` like this -> `RequestBody body =  
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), text);` for detailed answer https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use these in gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
```

> Use these two POJO class ........
>
> LoginData.class

```
public class LoginData {

    private String email;
    private String password;

    public LoginData(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param email
     * The email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param password
     * The password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

> LoginResult.class

```
public class LoginResult {

    private Boolean error;
    private String message;
    private Integer doctorid;
    private Boolean active;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The error
     */
    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param error
     * The error
     */
    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param message
     * The message
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The doctorid
     */
    public Integer getDoctorid() {
        return doctorid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param doctorid
     * The doctorid
     */
    public void setDoctorid(Integer doctorid) {
        this.doctorid = doctorid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The active
     */
    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param active
     * The active
     */
    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

> Use API like this

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
     @POST("User/DoctorLogin")
        Call<LoginResult> getStringScalar(@Body LoginData body);
}
```

> use call like this ....

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("Your domain URL here")
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

       RetrofitInterface service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface .class);

 Call<LoginResult> call=service.getStringScalar(new LoginData(email,password));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) { 
               //response.body() have your LoginResult fields and methods  (example you have to access error then try like this response.body().getError() )

              }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResult> call, Throwable t) {
           //for getting error in network put here Toast, so get the error on network 
                }
            });
```

**EDIT:-**

> put this inside the `success()` ....

```
if(response.body().getError()){
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}else {
          //response.body() have your LoginResult fields and methods  (example you have to access error then try like this response.body().getError() )
                String msg = response.body().getMessage();
                int docId = response.body().getDoctorid();
                boolean error = response.body().getError();  

                boolean activie = response.body().getActive()();   
}
```

Note :- Always use POJO classes , it remove the JSON data parsing in the retrofit .

Comment: works perfectly with `RequestBody` like this -> `RequestBody body =  
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), text);` for detailed answer https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body

Answer (score 18):

This way works for me

My web service
[image]

Add this in your gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
```

**Interface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    String ENDPOINT = "http://10.157.102.22/rest/";

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("login")
    Call<User> getUser(@Body String body);

}
```

**Activity**

```
   public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<User> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);


        // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
        try {
            JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
            paramObject.put("email", "sample@gmail.com");
            paramObject.put("pass", "4384984938943");

            Call<User> userCall = apiInterface.getUser(paramObject.toString());
            userCall.enqueue(this);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Using JSONObject might fail in cases , so it is always suggested to create custom Object. Refer Jake Wharton's comment here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/500

Comment: Calling `toString()` on JSONObject will fail because of wrong serialization, because it will send to server `"{\"email\":\"random@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"12345678\"}"`.

Comment: @soshial, Hi me also getting 500 error while passing the json string can you please help me out to resolve the issue...thank you

Comment: .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) works for me...Thanks @Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

i think you should now create a service generator class and after that
you should use Call to call your service

```
PostInterface postInterface = ServiceGenerator.createService(PostInterface.class);
Call<responseBody> responseCall =
            postInterface.getStringScalar(requestBody);
```

then you can use this for synchronous request and get the body of response:

```
responseCall.execute().body();
```

and for asynchronous :

```
responseCall.enqueue(Callback);
```

refer to link provided below for complete walkthrough and how to create ServiceGenerator :

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: best solution for Retrofit2

Answer (score 1):

From Retrofit 2+ use POJO objects rather than a JSON Object for sending requests with @Body annotations. With JSON object being sent the request fields are set to their default value than what has been sent from the app on backend. This won't be the case with POJO objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Json in Post Request

   ```
   val jsonObject = JSONObject()
               try {
                   jsonObject.put("name", name)
                   jsonObject.put("username", username)
                   jsonObject.put("email", email)
                   jsonObject.put("phone", phone)
                   jsonObject.put(
                       "token",
                       Prefs.getPrefInstance()!!.getValue(requireContext(), Const.TOKEN, "")
                   )
                   //                jsonObject.put("image", uploaded_image);
                   jsonObject.put("image", url)
               } catch (e: JSONException) {
                   binding.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                   e.printStackTrace()
               }
               val params = jsonObject.toString()
               val user_registering = params.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())
   ```