# Android Post Json Data to Web Service using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I don't know how to configure JSON Array in JSON Object and send JSON data to web service like this, please help me.

```
{
"Id":"1",
"UnitName":"-", 
"UnitCount":"1",
"UnitAmount":"1",
"CustomerId":"206", 
"PersonelId":"1", 
"CustomerCode":"PERSONEL-007", 
"OrderCode":"147",
"ItemList":[{

            "StockId":1,
            "Count":1,
            "Amount":1,
            "TotalAmount":1,
            "Discount1":"0",
            "Discount2":"0",
            "Discount3":"0",
            "Discount4":"0",
            "DiscountTotal":"0",
            "TaxPercent":"18",
            "TaxAmount":"1.18",
            "GrandTotal":"1.18"
}]
}
```

Comment: you need to follow this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

Comment: Get the basics clear first. Then read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending JSON in POST request with Retrofit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817362/sending-json-in-post-request-with-retrofit2)

Comment: Sorry, @Manmohan_singh my bad. I will pay attention after that.

Comment: Thanks, vikas and Henrique but how can I put json array in the json object?