# Retrofit Post Gives Null Response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I went through some Stack questions on this but couldn't find an answer.

Following is my request and response in PostMan

[image]

Following is my Retrofit code. I have a LoginModel POJO class with username and token as fields and their respective getters and setters:

```
object ApiClient {

    val BASE_URL = "http://MyIpaddress:3005/api/"
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    val client: Retrofit
        get() {
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build()
            }
            return retrofit!!
        }
}

public interface LoginApiInterface {



    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("v1/account/login")
    Call<LoginModel> saveLoginModel(@Body String body);
}
```

Following is the code which gets called when user clicks LoginButton

```
fun attemptLogin(){
        val email = et_email_activity_login.getText().toString()
        val password = et_password_activity_login.getText().toString()
        val apiInterface = ApiClient.client.create(LoginApiInterface::class.java)


        val jsonBody = JSONObject()
        jsonBody.put("email", email)
        jsonBody.put("password", password)
        val mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString()


        apiInterface.saveLoginModel(mRequestBody).enqueue(object: Callback<LoginModel>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.i("TAG",t!!.localizedMessage)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginModel>?, response: Response<LoginModel>?) {

                Log.i("TAG","Post submitted"+response!!.body().toString())

            }

        } )
```

I am getting null in `response!!.body().toString()`. When I did

```
if (response!!.code() == 400) {
                    Log.v("Error code 400",response!!.errorBody()!!.string());
                }
```

I got this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/pritish/Music/foodtruck-api/foodtruck-api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/home/pritish/Music/foodtruck-api/foodtruck-api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /home/pritish/Music/foodtruck-api/foodtruck-api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/home/pritish/Music/foodtruck-api/foodtruck-api/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (/home/pritish/Music/foodtruck-api/foodtruck-api/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/pritish/Music/foodtruck-api/foodtruck-api/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emitNone (events.js:115:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:218:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1054:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just check for the url from request and its parameters while debugging ..also check for headers and response code and probably there will be an error message embedded into it... go for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my server side code. I should have passed a JSON response after posting data.

Also this link helped a lot:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817362/sending-json-in-post-request-with-retrofit2/40817747#40817747
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the request is successful?

Add a http login interceptor to see what you send and receive when making the actual request. (https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor)

Also keep in mind that Retrofits onResponse is called for 4xx http response codes and your  body() is null then. For those cases you should use the errorBody. (onFailure is called for 500 error codes and other issues such as timeouts etc...

So do a following check as well in onRespose.

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) { // checks if res code is in [200..300)
   // Parse the response.body()
} else {
   // Parse the response.errorBody()
}
```