# How to post (x-www-form-urlencoded) Json Data using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

When I post data in body (x-www-form-urlencoded) it works fine in Postman. But using Retrofit 2.0 Android it does not work.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("/api/jsonws/pushUserData")
Call<ResponseBody>  pushData(@Body JSONObject jsonObj);

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("role","owner");
            jsonObject.put("id","27001");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ApiInterface apiInterface1= ApiClient.getClientAuthentication().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = apiInterface1.pushData(jsonObject);
```

This code not work.I also try @FormUrlEncoded.

Comment: you will get help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817362/sending-json-in-post-request-with-retrofit2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `@FormUrlEncoded` and use `@Field` instead of `@Body`

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/jsonws/pushUserData")
Call<ResponseBody>  pushData(@Field("role") String role, @Field("id") String id);

ApiInterface apiInterface1= ApiClient.getClientAuthentication().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = apiInterface1.pushData("owner","27001");
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1) . App is crashed

Comment: use `@Field` instead of `@Body`, see updated answer

Comment: thanks it work now fine

Comment: But if I am using @Field, then special character are getting coded in data