# How to send json data from Android to Asp.net

Tags: android, asp.net, json, http-post, asynchttpclient

**Help me to post json data from Android to Asp.net
Here is my code below. Android sending json data to webapi**

public class UploadByTableActivity extends Activity {

```
    final static String url = "https://webapi.com/api/post/";

    HttpResponse response;
    AsyncHttpClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploadbytable);

        Button btnWO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnwo);

        btnWorkOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
                String username = "id";
                String password = "pw";
                client =  new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
                client.addHeader(
                        "Authorization",
                        "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                                (username + ":"+ password).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP)
                );
                client.setEnableRedirects(true);
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                //  params.put("file", new File(pathoffile));
                params.put("name", "name1");
                params.put("phone", "111-111-1111");

                StringEntity entity = null;
                try {
                    entity = new StringEntity(params.toString());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                client.post(null,url,entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                        Log.i("appTag", "OK");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.i("appTag"," Error = " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Try to retrieve jsondata from webapi to asp.net but jsonString is null.
Please help me how to get json data.

```
[HttpPost]
public string post([FromBody]string jsonString){
    return jsonString; 
}
```

Comment: Hi you can use retrofit to avoid implementation complexity and easier thread management. Also on Asp .net site use Newton softs JObject to receive data.

Comment: hi use the retrofit https://stackoverflow.com/a/40817747/5027107