# Retrofit 400 Bad Request when posting rest api

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, webapi

I am trying to consume web api written in asp.net core 2.2 in android using Retrofit rest client. successfully Getting data from Api's but unable to Post Data to server using Retrofit. the webapi is working fine via postman and Javascript.

following is what i have tried..

**My Activity Class**

```
    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://sga.somee.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    private ShopApi _shopsApi;
    //constructor
    public MainActivity2(){
        //api classes must be initialized in constructors
         _shopsApi = retrofit.create(ShopApi.class);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
   Shop _shop = new Shop();
        _shop.shop_name = "Starbucks";
        _shop.shop_owner = "Unknown";
        _shop.shop_longitude = 49545.3455;
        _shop.shop_latitude = 55353.554;
        _shop.shop_image = "path/path.png";
        PostShop(_shop);
    }
    public void PostShop(Shop shop){
        /*
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.addProperty("shop_name",shop.shop_name);
        obj.addProperty("shop_owner",shop.shop_owner);
        obj.addProperty("shop_longitude",shop.shop_longitude);
        obj.addProperty("shop_latitude",shop.shop_latitude);
        obj.addProperty("shop_image",shop.shop_image);
        Log.d(TAG, obj.toString());
         */
        Call<ResponseBody> AddShop = _shopsApi.AddShop(shop);
        AddShop.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,response.raw().body().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"Failded to add new shop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**My ShopApi Class**

```
package com.example.madee.sga.API;

import com.example.madee.sga.Models.Shop;

import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface ShopApi {
    @GET("Shops/GetAll/{page}")
    Call<List<Shop>> GetAllShops(@Path("page") int page );


    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
    @POST("Shops/AddNew")
    Call<ResponseBody> AddShop(@Body Shop _shop);

}
```

You can also see that i have tried posting data with JsonObject too in MainActivity but same failure ***400 Bad Requset***

Answer (score 0):

This Error comes because you set params in body of **POST** request. Add Paramtere like this.

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Shops/AddNew")
Call<ResponseBody> AddShop(@Field("ShopName") String ShopName,  @Field("OwnerName") String OwnerName, @Field("Longitude") int Longitude,@Field("Latitude") int Latitude,@Field("Imagepath") String Imagepath,@Field("ShopId") String ShopId);
```

And call this function as:

```
Call<ResponseBody> AddShop = _shopsApi.AddShop(shop.shop_name, shop.shop_owner, shop.shop_longitude, shop.shop_latitude, shop.shop_image,shop.shop_id);
```

And i assumed your server accept same paramters name as u written in code. if it is not same changed it accordingly.

Comment: you can also see this
https://sga.somee.com/swagger/index.html

Comment: I updated the answer now its according to the server request. Last thing i add shop.shop_id parameter change it with orignal shop id.

Comment: Still getting following error
Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://sga.somee.com/api/Shops/AddNew}

Comment: shopid not required on the backend there is autoincrement

Comment: Have a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40817747/8918150